# Teradata : Error while converting Interval HOUR(2) TO MINUTE

Tags: teradata

I have a Teradata table where in a column the value is integer number and I have to convert it to HOUR(2) TO MINUTE.

I have tried the below statement but getting error like **Interval field overflow**

```
CAST(CAST(col1 AS DECIMAL(18,0)) * INTERVAL '0000:01' MINUTE TO SECOND AS INTERVAL HOUR(2) TO MINUTE) from table1
```

col1 contains integer value like 5192 or 8734 etc.

Comment: Kindly share sample value of `col1`.

Comment: Both values just converted fine at my end. i.e. `5192` and `8734` to `1:26` and `2:25` respectively in `BTET` as well as in `ANSI` mode in `sqla` and `bteq`. Kindly share `max` value from `col1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to teradata [documentation](http://info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1143-160K/bwn1472241380050.html):

The range of values for `INTERVAL HOUR TO MINUTE` is as follows.

```
Type and Precision           |  Minimum Value    |   Maximum Value
-----------------------------------------------------------------
INTERVAL HOUR(1) TO MINUTE       -'9:59'              '9:59'
INTERVAL HOUR(2) TO MINUTE       -'99:59'             '99:59'
INTERVAL HOUR(3) TO MINUTE       -'999:59'            '999:59'
INTERVAL HOUR(4) TO MINUTE       -'9999:59'           '9999:59'
```

For the sample data shared in question, the output value lies in the range of `INTERVAL HOUR(2) TO MINUTE` as shown below.

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(5192 AS DECIMAL(18,0)) * INTERVAL '0000:01' MINUTE TO SECOND AS INTERVAL HOUR(2) TO MINUTE) AS Value1,
       CAST(CAST(8734 AS DECIMAL(18,0)) * INTERVAL '0000:01' MINUTE TO SECOND AS INTERVAL HOUR(2) TO MINUTE) AS Value2;
```

**Result:**

```
Value1 | Value2
--------------
 1:26    2:25
```

It seems that some of your converted values are exceeding `99:59` in which case you have to use the 3rd option from the above.

For the given query and sample data, if any value is greater than `359999`, it will fail with error

> " *Interval field Overflow* "

Hope this will help :-)

Comment: The max value is 359999 and now 35999. I think it is just a typo from your end.